# iOS App crashes on facebook sdk login button

Tags: ios, facebook, cocos2d-iphone

I have a facebook login button on my main screen. I can log in and log out using that button as many times as I want, and it always work fine. Then on another layer, there is a button to share my score on facebook. There are two cases: Case1 is If I am logged in, it shares the score. And Case2 is if I am not logged in, it tells the user that I need to log in. This is my share button code:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:message
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {




                                UIAlertView *alert;
                                NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                if (!error)
                                {
                                    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You score" message:@"has been published" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                }
                                else{
                                    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"Please login to your facebook account" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                }

                                [alert show];
                                [alert release];
```

All this works as expected, but if I come back to the main screen where facebook login button is present from the case2 I described above, then if I click the login button, the facebook page of permissions open. When I click okay, the app crashes. It goes to delegate method `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` but before going to the delegate method `loginViewFetchedUserInfo`, it crashes. What can be the reason for it?

Comment: if you want someone to help you, then at leat post crash message from the console. it will be very helpful to understand your problem/